# PhantomJS doesn't start while websocket connection is open

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm working on slack bot and I've encountered curious problem. I have a module which scrapes web-page using phantomJS (via SpookyJS & CasperJS on top of it). I wrote this module and tested it running it from command line manually. It works well.  But then I added `slackbots` npm module which abstracts Slack realtime API, and created a module with bot class. This bot module requires my module with scraping code (phantomJS) and calls its function when message event triggers:

```
var getAnswer = require('./getAnswer');

myBot.prototype._onMessage = function (message) {
    if (this._isChatMessage(message) &&
        this._isChannelConversation(message) &&
        this._isMentioningMe(message)) {

        this._reply(message);
    }
};
```

`this._reply` basically just calls `getAnswer(originalMessage.text)` and then `self.postMessageToChannel(channel.name, reply, {as_user: true});`

getAnswer returns a promise, but it never get's fulfilled. I made CasperJS be `verbose` and saw that nothing happens after

```
[info] [phantom] Starting...
```

Everything just hangs...

I have no idea, how to fix this. I guess it's because `slackbots` module establishes websocket connection when I call `Bot.prototype.run`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with ports? Maybe nodejs has only one port available to it and therefore can't open two connections at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said I use Spooky to spawn child CasperJS process. I went to Spooky documentation page and read this:

> Specifically, each Spooky instance spawns a child Casper process that
>   runs a bootstrap script. The bootstrap script sets up a JSON-RPC
>   server that listens for commands from the parent Spooky instance over
>   a transport (either HTTP or stdio). The script also sets up a JSON-RPC
>   client that sends events to the parent Spooky instance via stdout.

I used `http` as a transport and it didn't work, so I changed it to stdio and it helped. I'd appreciate it if someone could explain *why* it helped?